# Why are most daemons shared objects

Tags: daemon

On redhat most of the systemd started services are implemented as shared objects. Why is this the case?

For instance:

```
file /usr/sbin/sshd
file /usr/sbin/squid 
file /usr/sbin/crond 
file /usr/sbin/rsyslogd
```

The output for all these daemons is `ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64`. I can understand why `systemd` itself is implemented as a shared object. When Kernel loads it there are no other shared objects/executables  in user space. So very likely `systemd` is full of direct system call instead of going through `libc`.

However what is the reason for the daemons listed above to be implemented as shared objects instead of executables?

Comment: Shared objects *are* executables...

Comment: I understand that both `shared objects` and `executables` have machine code in them. However, there is a distinction between the two. The `shared objects` code is a library of several functions that are shared among multiple executables.

Comment: That question is similar to asking why a building has an elevator and the other next to it doesn't.  If you want to ask about the benefits of using a shared object, ask so on http://stackoverflow.com where programming related questions are relevant.

Comment: See the answer to the question [Executables vs Shared objects](http://askubuntu.com/questions/690631/executables-vs-shared-objects). In brief: all shared objects are executables, but not all executables are shared objects.

Comment: Thanks @AlexP, that's a useful link! @sshekhar1980, try running your `libc.so.6`... Basically an ELF dynamically-linked executable is a shared object with a program header, and `file` doesn't look at that. [This LWN article](https://lwn.net/Articles/631631/) has more detail. Check out `ldd systemd`, you'll see it uses `libc` just like the other daemons you're asking about...

Comment: Which version do you see this on? Recently, various distros from various vendors have started to compile *all* executables as position-independent so that their code can be subjected to ASLR.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick I see this on RHEL 7.2 HVM (on aws).

Comment: As far as I can tell, RHEL 7 apparently continued Fedora's policy of compiling several dozen security-conscious packages as position-independent code. I can't find a RHEL-specific statement about this yet.